# Spring Data custom query in repository with object inheritance

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I'm working with Spring MVC + Data + Security and I'm having trouble with Spring Data. I have 3 entities (with different properties between them) which extend to another entity, and I'm trying to do a query from one of them based on the parent.

Here the code:

**Perfil** *(means Profile, but when I tried to use profile I got issues)* is the parent or super class of the other **3 classes**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Perfil {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    ...
```

And this is **Person**, which extends from **Perfil**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "perfil_id")
public class Person extends Perfil {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Gender gender;
```

And I have the **PersonRepository**. It has a method where I'm trying to find **Person** using the **Perfil ID**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.perfil_id=?1")
    Person findByProfileID(Integer id);
}
```

And I get this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: perfil_id of: com.giulianok.person.Person [SELECT p FROM com.giulianok.person.Person p WHERE p.perfil_id=?1]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

What I understand is Spring can't find "perfil_id" inside of Person, that make sense because I don't have that property, but at the end, when I take a look at the Database, I see the column "perfil_id"

The thing is, **how can I make the query based on Object inheritance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [JPQL](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL) so you need to use the object property in your query, not the database column :

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id=?1")
    Person findByProfileID(Integer id);
}
```

Note that the object property should be mapped to the right column with the @Column annotation if the property name differ from the database column name. i.e. that if the property id of the Perfil object is mapped to the perfil_id column, you should have :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "prefil_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```